# Localnotification with background mode, Without click on notification open an UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uilocalnotification

When my app is notify by local `notification` then without click on `notification` i want to open an `UIAlertView`. Is this possible for `IOS`?

I am attaching screenshot for detail understanding.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something like actionable notifications? - http://techcrunch.com/2014/06/02/actionable-push-notifications/

Comment: Yes i don't want to switch in my app. only with alert i want to add some text with user.

Comment: What do you mean text?  You can set whatever text you want when you schedule the notification, or you can add actions if that is what you want

Comment: Text means when notification plays at that time open an alert. Alert contains text field. When user enters his description in text field and click on save button at the same time data will insert in my DB.That's it don't want more...

Answer (score 0):

With iOS8 you can display actions for the user to choose from in the form of buttons. These buttons can launch your app in the background to perform some task or they can launch your app into the foreground as you can do with the notifications available in older versions of iOS.

You can't, however, display a UITextField for the user to enter data.